# what is the complexity of function that have loop inside recursion function

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, recursion

im trying to analysis the complexity of this code .
i predicated that its o(n^2)
because for loop take a o(n) inside a recursion function thats take o(n)
o(n) * o(n) = o(n^2)
however im not sure .

```
public class main 
{

    static Set<String> setString = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        main m = new main();
        m.permute("sanad", 0);
        for(String s : setString)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }


    public void permute(String str , int i )
    {
        if (i>=str.length())
        {
            return;
        }


        for(int j = 0 ; j < str.length();j++)
        {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str. replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)), ""));
            b.insert(j,str.charAt(i));
            setString.add(b.toString());
        }

        permute(str, ++i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to put all permutations of a string into your hashset?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the string will include only unique characters? If not, then your program is incorrect.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  unique string because this i am using set .

Comment: @JaysonBoubin yes . but what i am thinking to solve this  question on o(n)

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. In the code, you are checking the string `sanad`. That string has two `a`.  That means that you should have "asnad", "sanad", "snaad", "snada" from permuting the first "a", then "asand","saand","sanad","sanda" from permuting the second "a". Do you get that?

Comment: @user3512497, Unfortunately that's not possible. A set of N objects has N! permutations. If you have to generate N! outputs, then your algorithm has to be at least O(n!).

Comment: @JaysonBoubin . I think you didn't understand me i have only one object string , what i want to do is to find all   permutations and put it into a hashset

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes i get that . this my console output sdana
sanad
snaad
ansad
anads
snada
saand
sadna
anasd
asnad
dsana
nsaad
saadn
sanda

Comment: @RealSkeptic maybe you can help to provide idea to solve the question on a linear way o(n)

Comment: Nope... if a program has to create N! solutions, then it is O(N!). It has to at least write each solution once somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in that the total complexity is the product of the nested complexities and that the permute function is called *n* times, where *n* is the length of the string, and the loop is called *n* times as well, leading to *n^2* calls of the loop . However you also have to look at the complexity of the code inside the loop, especially `replaceFirst` and `insert`, decide, if their runtime depends on the length of the string, and multiply with that as well. As I suspect this is a homework question I leave this to you.

Comment: thanks ... no its not a homework what i need to do is to solve this question using o(n) complexity